# sobrescribir fotografía cuando la estoy usando en un PictureBox

Tags: c#, windows-forms, picturebox

tengo almacenada ya en mi base de datos una fotografia con un codigo como nombre y para sobreescribir el mismo archivo jpg me dice que esta siento utilizada

```
if (OpcionAbrirGuardar.Text == "Guardar")
{
    int cod = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.Text);
    string filename = Application.StartupPath + "\\Fotos\\" + cod + ".jpg";

    if (File.Exists(filename))
    {
        File.Delete(filename);
        pictureBoxLienzo.Image.Save(filename);
        MessageBox.Show("Fotografia Actualizada");
        groupBoxFoto.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        pictureBoxLienzo.Image.Save(filename);
        MessageBox.Show("Fotografia Guardada");
        groupBoxFoto.Visible = false;
    }
}
OpcionAbrirGuardar.Text = "Guardar";
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es que la tiene tomada tu picturebox... cual es la necesidad de borrarla si la vas a sobreescribir?

Comment: solución para sobrescribir una foto que esta siento usada por el pictureBox ???

Comment: Pues supongo que estas haciendo uso de la imagen, tal vez falta un pedazo de codigo donde estas utilizando la imagen,¿Utilizas la imagen que quieres eliminar en algún lugar?